# Rubberduck Test Module Creation

Tags: c#, strings, vba, rubberduck

I recently started learning C# and am taking the opportunity to try and accelerate my introduction by helping the RubberDuck team ([Website](http://rubberduckvba.com/) and [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)). The full class code that I'm working on [can be found here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/dd0bb517d7a984bb42a4d0284d29d55e48288c05/RetailCoder.VBE/UI/Command/AddTestModuleCommand.cs). Its purpose is to create a Module in VBA that will allow unit testing.

1. Since `FakesFieldDeclarationFormat` and
   `AssertFieldDeclarationFormat` are used only once would it be better
   to move them to just above where they are fed into
   `DeclarationFormatFor`?
2. Would it be better to migrate `FolderAnnotation` into
   `TestModuleEmptyTemplate` since when `formattedModuleTemplate` is
   created that is ultimately what is happening?
3. Does anyone have any suggestions for improving the names?
4. Anything else that help improve the code and that may assist me in learning is welcome.

The main code in question is below.

```cs
    private const string TestModuleEmptyTemplate = "'@TestModule\r\n{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}\r\n\r\n";
    private const string FolderAnnotation = "'@Folder(\"Tests\")\r\n";

    private const string FakesFieldDeclarationFormat = "Private Fakes As {0}";
    private const string AssertFieldDeclarationFormat = "Private Assert As {0}";

    private readonly string _moduleInit = string.Concat(
        "'@ModuleInitialize\r\n",
        "Public Sub ModuleInitialize()\r\n",
        $"    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.\r\n",
        "    {0}\r\n",
        "    {1}\r\n",
        "End Sub\r\n\r\n",
        "'@ModuleCleanup\r\n",
        "Public Sub ModuleCleanup()\r\n",
        $"    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.\r\n",
        "    Set Assert = Nothing\r\n",
        "    Set Fakes = nothing\r\n",
        "End Sub\r\n\r\n"
    );

    private readonly string _methodInit = string.Concat(
        "'@TestInitialize\r\n"
        , "Public Sub TestInitialize()\r\n"
        , "    '", RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunBeforeTest, ".\r\n"
        , "End Sub\r\n\r\n"
        , "'@TestCleanup\r\n"
        , "Public Sub TestCleanup()\r\n"
        , "    '", RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunAfterTest, ".\r\n"
        , "End Sub\r\n\r\n"
    );

    private const string TestModuleBaseName = "TestModule";

    private string GetTestModule(IUnitTestSettings settings)
    {
        var assertType = string.Format("Rubberduck.{0}AssertClass", settings.AssertMode == AssertMode.StrictAssert ? string.Empty : "Permissive");
        var assertDeclaredAs = DeclarationFormatFor(AssertFieldDeclarationFormat, assertType, settings);

        var fakesType = "Rubberduck.IFake";
        var fakesDeclaredAs = DeclarationFormatFor(FakesFieldDeclarationFormat, fakesType, settings); 

        var formattedModuleTemplate = string.Format(TestModuleEmptyTemplate, FolderAnnotation, assertDeclaredAs, fakesDeclaredAs);

        if (settings.ModuleInit)
        {
            var assertBinding = InstantiationFormatFor(assertType, settings);
            var assertSetAs = $"Set Assert = {assertBinding}";

            var fakesBinding = InstantiationFormatFor(fakesType, settings);
            var fakesSetAs = $"Set Fakes = {fakesBinding}";

            formattedModuleTemplate += string.Format(_moduleInit, assertSetAs, fakesSetAs);
        }

        if (settings.MethodInit)
        {
            formattedModuleTemplate += _methodInit;
        }

        return formattedModuleTemplate;
    }

    private string InstantiationFormatFor(string type, IUnitTestSettings settings) 
    {
        const string EarlyBoundInstantiationFormat = "New {0}";
        const string LateBoundInstantiationFormat = "CreateObject(\"{0}\")";
        return string.Format(settings.BindingMode == BindingMode.EarlyBinding ? EarlyBoundInstantiationFormat : LateBoundInstantiationFormat, type); 
    }

    private string DeclarationFormatFor(string declarationFormat, string type, IUnitTestSettings settings) 
    {
        return string.Format(declarationFormat, settings.BindingMode == BindingMode.EarlyBinding ? type : "Object");
    }
```

The final output for VBA:

Early Binding:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

Private Assert As Rubberduck.AssertClass
Private Fakes As Rubberduck.IFake

'@ModuleInitialize
Public Sub ModuleInitialize()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = New Rubberduck.AssertClass
    Set Fakes = New Rubberduck.IFake
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Public Sub ModuleCleanup()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Set Fakes = Nothing
End Sub

'@TestInitialize
Public Sub TestInitialize()
    'this method runs before every test in the module.
End Sub

'@TestCleanup
Public Sub TestCleanup()
    'this method runs after every test in the module.
End Sub
```

Late Binding:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'@Folder("Tests")

Private Assert As Object
Private Fakes As Object

'@ModuleInitialize
Public Sub ModuleInitialize()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = CreateObject("Rubberduck.AssertClass")
    Set Fakes = CreateObject("Rubberduck.IFake")
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Public Sub ModuleCleanup()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Set Fakes = Nothing
End Sub

'@TestInitialize
Public Sub TestInitialize()
    'this method runs before every test in the module.
End Sub

'@TestCleanup
Public Sub TestCleanup()
    'this method runs after every test in the module.
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, should've caught that on github - `Set Fakes = New Rubberduck.IFake` should be `Set Fakes = New Rubberduck.FakesProvider`, declared as `IFakesProvider` - an `IFake` would be e.g. `MsgBoxFake`, and we don't `New` up an interface just like that anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only targeting `_moduleInit` and `_methodInit`

IMO the use of `string.Concat` with many parameters together with `\r\n` is hurting the readability a lot.

How about using a `StringBuilder` instead like so

```
private readonly string _moduleInit = new StringBuilder(256)
    .AppendLine("'@ModuleInitialize")
    .AppendLine("Public Sub ModuleInitialize()")
    .AppendLine($"    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.")
    .AppendLine("    {0}")
    .AppendLine("    {1}")
    .AppendLine("End Sub")
    .AppendLine()
    .AppendLine("'@ModuleCleanup")
    .AppendLine("Public Sub ModuleCleanup()")
    .AppendLine($"    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.")
    .AppendLine("    Set Assert = Nothing")
    .AppendLine("    Set Fakes = Nothing")
    .AppendLine("End Sub")
    .AppendLine()
    .ToString();
```

which is easier to read. Now you will also notice that the `Nothing` in `Set Fakes = Nothing` is cased correctly.

For `_methodInit` this should be applied as well and you should decide if you want to use string interpolation `$` or not. You used it for `_moduleInit` but you didn't for `_methodInit`. If you have choosen a style, you should stick to it.

Comment: Since I'm learning why is `StringBuilder` preferred? It does make it easier to read but is that the only reason as to *why* it's used?  Casing was an oversight. Regarding the constructor, I think that's the correct term, for `StringBuilder` why provide the 256 number into it?

Comment: If you are using `String.Concat()` then `StringBuilder` isn't preffered but if you are concating strings by using `+` in a loop then each time you do this a new string object is created because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use large string literals for your `_moduleInit` and `_methodInit` values, as they are more visually alike to their expected output:

```
    private readonly string _moduleInit =
$@"'@ModuleInitialize
Public Sub ModuleInitialize()
    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.
    {{0}}
    {{1}}
End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Public Sub ModuleCleanup()
    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunOnce}.
    Set Assert = Nothing
    Set Fakes = nothing
End Sub

";

    private readonly string _methodInit =
$@"'@TestInitialize
Public Sub TestInitialize()
    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunBeforeTest}.
End Sub


'@TestCleanup
Public Sub TestCleanup()
    '{RubberduckUI.UnitTest_NewModule_RunAfterTest}.
End Sub

";
```

The `{{}}` tells the interpolated string to output braces rather than attempt to perform a replacement, so it keeps the format placeholders intact, so that's no worry for the entire string being interpolated.

Comment: The thing I don't like about this, is that it wrecks the indentation. We use multiline verbatim strings in unit tests, but not in the actual RD code base.

Comment: Didn't know about doubling up the `{{` `}}`, now I do. Is the double curly braces only for interpolated strings? Paralleling how one has to escape certain characters in a literal string.

Comment: @IvenBach it's a way to escape curly braces for any kind of string formatting.  Since interpolated strings are really just syntactic sugar on top of string formatting, it works there as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's one more alternative. Put the texts in `*.txt` files and compile them as **Embeded Resource**. Then your code is free of string concatenations. Define **placeholders** to insert custom values where necessary.

See [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)